# ASK XPATH 3.0 with WSO2-ESB

Tags: wso2, xslt-3.0

i want integration XSLT 3.0 with WSO2 Integration Studio 7.2, how to do that. i newbie with this tools studio. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this post [1] is exactly what you are looking for.

[1] - https://medium.com/think-integration/how-to-transform-xml-using-xslt-in-wso2-enterprise-integrator-d6cc35c45ef

Comment: i was doing like this before. i need install xslt 3.0 in integration studio. but i dont know how do that.

Answer (score 0):

The currently released Integration Studio(8.1.0) and the runtime Micro Integrator(4.1.0) don't support XSLT version 3. It only supports versions 1 and 2. Future releases may support XSLT version 3.